# Issue in bootsratp multiselect js

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-multiselect

#### Issue in Bootstrap multi select

I can't see how to enable/disable a particular option in multi select drop-down using bootstrap multi select.
I tried using http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Any solution?

Comment: Did you find any errors in the browser F12 tools (console tab)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ddl1` is the `ID` of the drop down control you are working on,

This is how you are supposed to create the control in your `HTML`(again assuming you are using MVC Razor)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyModelObj, Model.MyModelObjs, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddl1", multiple = "multiple", placeholder = "Select" })
```

and this is how you apply the bootstrap multiselect plugin to your drop down

```
$('#ddl1').multiselect({
            enableClickableOptGroups: true,
            enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select',
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            selectAllNumber: true,
            onChange: function(option, checked,select) {
                FillOtherDropdown();
                },
                onSelectAll: function(){
                $("#ddl2").html("");
                $('#ddl2').multiselect('refresh' );
                $("#ddl2").multiselect('disable');}
});
```

All the properties can be applied as shown above i.e. `PropertyName : Value`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding disabled attribute to the option you want to disable like the below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <select>
            <option>Select</option>
   <option disabled>value</option>
   <option>value</option>
   <option>value</option>
   <option disabled>value</option>
   <option>value</option>
   <option>value</option>
  </select>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').multiselect();
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is so Easy just by adding disabled attribute to the option you are targeting:-

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
      });
      $('#example-enableClickableOptGroups-disabled').multiselect();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>!-->
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js">
  </script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <br />
  <select id="lstFruits" multiple="">
    <option value="1">Mango</option>
    <option value="2">Apple </option>
    <option value="3">Banana </option>
    <option value="4">Guava </option>
    <option value="5">Orange </option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <label>with disabled options</label> <br/>
  <select id="example-enableClickableOptGroups-disabled" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1-1" disabled="">Option 1.1</option>
    <option value="1-2">Option 1.2</option>
    <option value="1-3">Option 1.3</option>
    <option value="2-1" disabled="">Option 2.1</option>
    <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
    <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

and Here is A full [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KLFapI0e4rigJcxN9m3I?p=preview)

Hope that Helps.